# How do I put 3 div's side by side and center the content in each one

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css so please explain in easy terms. I want 3 divs the same size as each other beside each other with the content in each div to be centered. What I have is a center div with a rotating image and my left and right divs each contain 3 links. I've tried everything from setting the width for each div to floating the left left and right right and centering the middle. I've looked at some other questions like this one on this site but I don't understand any of the answers. If it helps I'm using the following names for my divs:

topleftnav

topcenter

toprightnav

Code:

```
<div id="top">
  <div id="topleftnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="centerright">
   <div id="topcenter">
       <layer id="placeholderlayer"></layer><div id="placeholderdiv"><a href="link.htm"><img alt="image2 (9K)" src="images/image2.jpg" border="0"></a></div>
   </div>
   <div id="toprightnav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: If it helps the site as is is located at http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample/home.html

Comment: If you put `text-align="center"` on your `placeholderdiv` it should center the link for you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to support browsers more than 13 years old? Remove the layer tag and change 
function rotater() {
  document.getElementById("placeholderdiv").innerHTML=items[current];
  current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1; 
  setTimeout(rotater,howOften*1000);
  }

Answer (score 1):

CSS

`#1 { width: 33%;
        display: inline
        text-align: center;`
'#2 { width: 33%;
        display: inline
        text-align: center;
`'#3 { width: 33%;
        display: inline
        text-align: center;`

Comment: add a float:left; if not going inline. if using html5 change divs to <section>. Vote up

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.yourDivStyle {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;

}
.insideDiv {
 text-align: center;   
}

</style>

<div class="yourDivStyle"><p class="insideDiv">div 1</p></div>
<div class="yourDivStyle"><p class="insideDiv">div 2</p></div>
<div class="yourDivStyle"><p class="insideDiv">div 2</p></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg6DK/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <DIV id="container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <DIV id="topleftnav" style="float: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; width: 200px;">
                Hello from the left
            </DIV>
            <DIV id="centerNav" style="float: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; width: 200px;">
                Hello from the middle
            </DIV>
            <DIV id="rightNav" style="float: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; width: 200px;">
                Hello from the right
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution. adjust the width values to your needs.

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #container 
    {
        width:600px;
    }
    #centernav 
    {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
    }
    #topleftnav 
    {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
    }
    #toprightnav 
    {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
    }
    .center 
    {
        width:150px;
        margin:auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="topleftnav">
            <div class="center">
                LEFTNAV
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="centernav">
            <d iv class="center">
                CENTER
            </div>

        <div id="toprightnav">
            <div class="center">
                RIGHTNAV
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#top div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
}
```