# Center contents of fluid middle div in three column layout

Tags: css

I cannot for the life of me get the contents of the center div to align no matter what I try:

HTML

```
<div class="content-controls">
    <div class="content-controls-left">
        123
    </div>
    <div class="content-controls-middle">
        <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content-controls-right">
        456
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-controls {
    width:100%;
}
.content-controls-left {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
.content-controls-right {
    float:right;
    width:35px;
}
.content-controls-middle {
    float:left;
    margin:auto 0;
}
```

What I would like to happen is that the image in the middle column is always centred in content-controls-middle - I have tried suggestions in:

1. [CSS: center element within a <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element)
2. [How do I put 3 div's side by side and center the content in each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070474/how-do-i-put-3-divs-side-by-side-and-center-the-content-in-each-one)
3. [Three DIVs next to each other with fluid horizontal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826542/three-divs-next-to-each-other-with-fluid-horizontal-width)
4. [Align image in center and middle within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888223/align-image-in-center-and-middle-within-div)

and more but all to no avail - what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/8VS5U/

Comment: Add this to middle div:  margin-left:40%;

Comment: Should the middle div take up the rest of the space? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8VS5U/1/)

Comment: when you could consider changing your html, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/8VS5U/6/

Comment: @NicoO Your suggestion worked best for me - the others worked fine in the fiddles but I assume there is something else in the remaining code not shown here within my site which stopped those from working but this works, thanks

Comment: @bhttoan NicoO's one is the same as mine. They just put an image in the middle instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a `table` layout if your middle cell will only contain `inline` content (which an image is):

```css
/* Set container to display as a table. */
.content-controls {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
}

/* Set div elements within container to display as table cells. */
.content-controls div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.content-controls-left {
    width:50px;
}
.content-controls-right {
    width: 35px;
}

/* Centrally align middle cell content. */
.content-controls-middle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VS5U/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can change your CSS like this, it will allow the middle div to take the remainer space so you can just text-align the content.

**CSS:**

```
.content-controls {
    width:100%;
}
.content-controls-left {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
.content-controls-right {
    float:right;
    width:35px;
}
.content-controls-middle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And you must change the HTML like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-controls">
    <div class="content-controls-left">123</div>
    <div class="content-controls-right">456</div>
    <div class="content-controls-middle">ABC</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8VS5U/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `margin-left:40%;` on your `.content-controls-middle`.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/8VS5U/7/

As James points out, if you make the window smaller, it won't be central. But this is good enough if you are not making a responsive website. I would prefer James' answer if you want a solid approach, and mine if you want a hacky way to do it :)

Comment: If you make the results frame smaller you'll see that this isn't central.

Comment: Well, he will have to play with the % to be precise. Your answer is better.